# Is there a better way to randomly generate a Doubly Stochastic Matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is a profile of the call `n = 2*10^3; M = DStochMat02(n,ones(n)./n);`

```
 time   calls  line
                  1 function M = DStochMat02(n,c)
                  2 % Generate a random doubly stochastic matrix using
                  3 % Theorem (Birkhoff [1946], von Neumann [1953])
                  4 % Any doubly stochastic matrix M can be written as a convex combination
                  5 % of permutation matrices P1,...,Pk (i.e. M = c1*P1+...+ ck*Pk
                  6 % for nonnegative c1,...,ck with c1+...+ck = 1).
                  7 % Complexity: O(n^2)
                  8 % USE: M = DStochMat02(4,[1/2 1/8 1/8 1/4])
                  9 % Derek O'Connor, Oct 2006, Nov 2012. derekroconnor@eircom.net
  0.02       1   10 M = zeros(n,n);
< 0.01       1   11 I = eye(n);
< 0.01       1   12 for k = 1:n
   1.64   2000   13     pidx = GRPdur(n);                                 % Random Permutation
 107.72   2000   14     P = I(pidx,:);                                    % Random P matrix
  41.09   2000   15     M = M + c(k)*P;
< 0.01    2000   16 end


function p = GRPdur(n)
% -------------------------------------------------------------
% Generate a random permutation p(1:n) using Durstenfeld's
% Shuffle Algorithm, CACM, 1964.
% See Knuth, Section 3.4.2, TAOCP, Vol 2, 3rd Ed.
% Complexity: O(n)
% USE: p = GRPdur(10^7);
% Derek O'Connor, 8 Dec 2010.  derekroconnor@eircom.net
% -------------------------------------------------------------

    p = 1:n;                  % Start with Identity permutation
for k = n:-1:2
    r = 1+floor(rand*k);      % random integer between 1 and k
    t    = p(k);
    p(k) = p(r);               % Swap(p(r),p(k)).
    p(r) = t;
end
return % GRPdur
```

Comment: why not use standard function [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) instead of `GRPdur`?

Comment: @max taldykin   Because the old randperm was (is) inefficient of time and space. The latest versions of Matlab use their implementation of Durstenfeld's algorithm, which is optimal in time and space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing lines `14` and `15` to the following lines:

```
l = ( [ pidx ; 1:n ] - 1 ) * [1;n] + 1; % convert pairs (pidx,1:n) to linear indices
M(l) = M(l) + c(k);
```

since `P` is very sparse, maybe it would be more efficient to increment only the non-zeros of `P`.

Comment: Spot on! This is excellent and is the same as the method given by Matt Fighere:    http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/53957-is-there-a-better-way-to-randomly-generate-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix                                                                It is up to 300 times faster than my matlab function.

Comment: @DerekO'Connor i haven't seen the mathworks solution - good to know my matlab is up-to-date. Thanks!