# Random permutation matrix

Tags: matlab, permutation

Is there an easy way to simulate a random permutation matrix (say of size 1000 by 1000) in Matlab? I would like to study the eigenvalue distribution of independent sum of such matrices.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429144/is-there-a-better-way-to-randomly-generate-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate a [random permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) like so:

1. Create a unity matrix:

   ```
   A = eye( N );  %// N is the size of your matrix
   ```

   For large values of `N` it is better to use [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/full-and-sparse-matrices.html):

   ```
   A = speye( N ); % create sparse identity matrix
   ```
2. Generate a random permutation:

   ```
   idx = randperm(1:N);
   ```
3. Use vector indexing to rearrange the rows accordingly

   ```
   A = A(idx, :);
   ```

Voila!

Comment: For large `N` it is better to use `speye` rather than `eye`... no need to store so many zeros... ;-)

Comment: @Shai Why did you remove your answer? There was nothing wrong about it!

Comment: once `speye` was integrated into your solution there is no need for duplications... no extra knowledge exists there

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab (used R2012a) `idx = randperm(1:N)` gives a warning that input should be scalar. So: `idx = randperm(N);` .