# Need help in creating a matrix with exactly one 1 in each row/column at different locations

Tags: matlab

This code generates a matrix having 1 in each row and this 1 may be on same locations in rows.
I want for each row the location of 1 must be different i.e 1 must not overlap in columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at MATLAB's [`randperm`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381770/random-permutation-matrix

Comment: @BillBokeey "1 may be on same locations in rows" -> this is NOT a permutation matrix.

Comment: @Shai "I want for each row the location of 1 must be different" I admit OP shouldn't say 2 exactly opposite things in 2 sentences but meh. I guess he's actually looking for a permutation matrix even if it's unclear

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want the result matrix to be of size `[m, n]`.
First, randomly select , for each column, the index of the `1`

```
idx = randi(m, 1, n);
```

Second, allocate an all-zero matrix of size `[m,n]`

```
res = zeros(m,n);
```

Finally, set the corresponding entries to one:

```
res( sub2ind([m,n], idx, 1:n) ) = 1;
```

An example result for `[3,4]` matrix:

```
res =
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, however I only want one 1 in each row and column. No column and row can have more than one 1. I have code using randperm<<function [m]=Matrix(rows,columns,onesPerRows)
rows =5;
columns=5;
onesPerRows=1;
m = zeros(rows,columns);
 

for row= 1 : rows 
    randcolumns = randperm(columns);
            
   columnsWithOne = randcolumns(1:onesPerRows);
      
    m(row, columnsWithOne) = 1;           
    end
m
end