# Generating Conditional Random Matrices

Tags: python

How we can generate a matrix with columns and rows with the sum of 1.

```
import numpy as np
import random
class city:

    def  __init__(self):
        self.distance()

    def  distance(self):
        self.A = np.array([[ 0,  10,    20,  30],[10,   0,    25,  20],[20,  25,      0,  15],[30,  20,    15,   0]])
        self.B =(np.random.randint(0, self.A.shape[0], size=self.A.shape[0]) == np.arange(self.A.shape[0]).reshape(-1, 1)).astype(int)
        return self.B
```

Comment: Sum of 1? Please reword your question as it's unclear what you want.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003153/how-to-generate-a-matrix-with-random-entries-and-with-constraints-on-row-and-col

Comment: Only +ve numbers or -ve also allowed?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you want a generator for random [doubly stochastic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) (DSM).

If you don't need any additional properties for the distribution of the generated matrices, the algorithm of choice still seems to be [Sinkhorn-Knopp](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38346604_Concerning_nonnegative_matrices_and_doubly_stochastic_matrices). Here, we alternatingly rescale row and columns so that the values conform to the sum criterion:

```
def gen_doubly_stochastic(size, max_error=None):
    if max_error is None:
        max_error = 1024 * np.finfo(float).eps

    m = np.matrix(np.random.random((size, size)))
    error = float('Inf')
    while error > max_error:
        m = np.divide(m, m.sum(axis=0), order='C')
        m = np.divide(m, m.sum(axis=1), order='K')

        error = max(
            np.max(np.abs(1 - m.sum(axis=0))),
            np.max(np.abs(1 - m.sum(axis=1)))
        )
    return m
```

Following the original paper, the iteration converges pretty rapidly towards an approximated solution.

Alternatively, one can make use of the property that any `n x n` DSM can be expressed as a linear combination of `n` random permutation matrices (see e.g. [Is there a better way to randomly generate a Doubly Stochastic Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429144/is-there-a-better-way-to-randomly-generate-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix)), with the sum of the linear coefficients summing up to 1:

```
def gen_doubly_stochastic_permute(size):
    m = np.zeros((size, size))
    I = np.identity(size)

    # n random coefficients
    coeffs = np.random.random(size)
    # enforce coefficient sum == 1
    coeffs /= np.sum(coeffs)

    # index array for identity permutation
    values = np.array(range(0, size))
    for c in coeffs:
        # generate new random permutation in place
        np.random.shuffle(values)
        # add scaled permutation matrix
        m += c * I[values, :]
    return m
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow dear Davood.
**here is my algorithm to solve this problem:**
let's say that we want the dimensions of the matrix to be 4*4  (like what is seen in the picture, make sure to watch it)

1. first, we create four random numbers whose sum equals to 1, to put into the top most unfilled row.
2. second, we try to fill the left-most column below the last filled row such that the column's sum equals to 1.

up to now we have filled the yellow part(picture)
at the next iteration the orange part is filled . and so on.
here is the code (it's been tested)

[image: picture of algorithm]

```
# RMG.py

import numpy as np
from random import random

class RMG:
    
    def __init__(self, dimension, sum_=1):
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.sum = sum_


    def generate_matrix(self):
        # create a matrix filled with zero s
        row_num = self.dimension
        col_num = self.dimension
        matrix = np.zeros((row_num, col_num))
        for i in range(self.dimension):
            
            matrix[i, i:self.dimension] = \
                self.create_numbers(1-sum(matrix[i, 0:i])
                , self.dimension-i)
            
            if i == self.dimension -1:
                break

            matrix[i+1:self.dimension, i] = \
                self.create_numbers(1-sum(matrix[0:i+1, i]), self.dimension - i - 1)
        return matrix

    @classmethod
    def create_numbers(cls, wanted_sum, count):
        
        result = [random() for i in range(count)]
        diff = wanted_sum - sum(result)
        to_be_added = diff/count
        result = \
            list(
                map(
                    lambda x: x + to_be_added,
                    result
                    )
                )
        # to fix the approximations of float type:
        result[-1] += wanted_sum - sum(result)
        return result
```

this is the derived class in `RMGInteger.py`:

```
from RMG import RMG
from random import randint


class RMGInteger(RMG):
    
    def __init__(self, dimension, sum_=1):
        super(RMGInteger, self).__init__(dimension, sum)

    @classmethod
    def create_numbers(cls, wanted_sum, count):
        index = randint(0, count-1)
        result = [0 if i!= index else wanted_sum for i in range(count)]
        return result
```

and this the file to be executed:

```
# main.py

from RMG_Integer import RMGInteger

def main():

    handler = RMGInteger(4, 1)
    matrix = handler.generate_matrix()
    print(matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# outputs something like this:
# [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

## update:

according to what @Davood mentioned in the comments, the code was revised.
I wrote a derived class, which does the same job but produces a matrix with just zero or one values.

Comment: Hello dear Shahryar. Unfortunately its not exactly what I wanted. I want  the following output:

Comment: [[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1]]

Comment: And finally, return the cell address of those that gets the value of 1. as an array. Something like this:

Comment: [(0,1),(1,2),(2,0),(3,3)]

Comment: [[0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: @Davood: Are you sure? In that example, the first row sum is `2`.

Comment: @Davood is the matrix you want, a square matrix?

Comment: Hello dear Shahryar. Apoloize for late response. Yes.

Comment: @Davood As soon as possible I'll update the answer to meet your need .